# Scroll view not fire any scroll events

Tags: react-native, expo, native-base

I use a Scrollview from React Native, here is my code:

```
        <ScrollView 
        onScroll={ e => this.handleOnScroll(e) }
        onMomentumScrollEnd={ e => this.handleOnScroll(e) }
        onContentSizeChange={console.log}
        scrollEventThrottle={1}
        nestedScrollEnabled={true}
        >
```

All the events connected to scroll aren't fired, how to solve this?
I've also tried to use  from Native Base, but even the same problem, no events fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I've looked for long time, the solution is simple, need to use a container in the same element, if the  is only in parent elements not working.

```
        <Container>
            <Content 
            onScroll={ this.handleOnScroll }
            onMomentumScrollEnd={ e => this.handleOnScroll(e) }
            onContentSizeChange={console.log}
            scrollEventThrottle={1}
            nestedScrollEnabled={true}
            >
                <Button onPress={this.getPosts}>
                    <Text>
                        WALL MIX
                    </Text>         
                </Button>
                {   this.state.thePosts.map( (post) => {
                        return <ThePost key={post[0].id} thePost={post} />

                    })
                }
            </Content>
        </Container>
```